# Sharing my computer with someone to run heavy CPU/GPU compute while I continue to use it

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, python, gpu, vnc

I'd like to give access to my powerful Windows 10 Pro machine to someone from the outside (who I trust completely) to run Python/PyTorch programs, using the GPU for compute.

The key is that I'd like to continue using the machine while that person runs compute loads on it: as far as I know, that requirement excludes all forms of RDP/VNC, but I'm not sure about that (especially RDP): could you confirm/deny?

I was thinking of running a SSH server. Would that work?

Comment: Any time my computer is busy with a very heavy load, it tends to bog down other processing. That will be independent of how you connect.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be a problem on this machine. My question is more how to give access while I remain logged in and do actual work with my user account. Could the person connect to another use account via RDP without interfering (apart from stealing cycles)?

Comment: One way to connect (I use it) is to set up a Radmin Server. Set that up on your machine, Radmin viewer is free. The other person can connect without affecting your login state.

Comment: Do you know if something like TeamViewer (or even better, plain RDP) would work as well?

Comment: Plain RDP will not keep the user session. I use this. Team Viewer works but is limited to single use, non-commercial.

Comment: The non-commercial aspect of TV is not a problem, this isn't for commercial purposes whatsoever. By single use, you mean a single remote connection right? Are the instructions to use TV to connect to a second user account look like these: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/General-Questions-EN/Can-I-connect-multiple-accounts-to-1-PC/m-p/50671

Comment: I mean one user at a time. You could not use non-commercial Team Viewer for multiple users to access.

Comment: (1) How many GPUs do you have? (2) What is your computer exact model/make? (3) What kind of programs will you be running while the GPU is used that way?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune I believe my answer addresses these issues/questions you have.

Comment: If your question is resolved and you don't desire additional explanation or details, be sure to select a "Best Answer", based on the answer that you feel best answered the question you asked. This benefits the exchange userbase by pulling this question out of the "Unanswered Questions" so that people looking to help and answer questions don't spend time reading through questions just to see that they already have proper answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 10 includes an OpenSSH server as a standard feature.

To enable the OpenSSH server:

- Open *Settings > Apps > Apps & features*
- On the right, click *Optional features*
- In the Optional features window, click *Add a feature*
- In the list of features, locate "OpenSSH Server".
  The feature can be more easily found by typing "open" in the selection field
  (this is enough to find the feature).
- Click on the entry and then on its "Install" button
- Wait for it to finish and restart Windows 10.

[image]

This will install the OpenSSH Server software in the folder
`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`, which will contain SSH client apps
and the following server tools: `sftp-server.exe`, `ssh-agent.exe`,
`ssh-keygen.exe`, `sshd.exe` and the config file `sshd_config`.

The SSH server is configured to run as a service named `sshd`.
If it doesn't start automatically, you need to configure it manually.

Answer (score 4):

To configure the built-in OpenSSH server in Windows 10, you could check quite a few references out there, including the answer by harrymc.
I am simply adding here [a link to official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) for this, just in case it helps.

But I am not certain that alone is enough, or only a requirement for some of the methods for sharing GPU, see the following.

### Distributed RPC

One option for sharing GPU for PyTorch is to use [Distributed RPC](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/rpc_tutorial.html) (PyTorch v1.4 is recommended).
The link provides a tutorial that "uses two simple examples to demonstrate how to build distributed training with the `torch.distributed.rpc` package".
It is quite long to be quoted here, even a set of basic steps.

See also

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/rpc.html

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/send-computation-to-a-remote-gpu/71739

Your friend could also *debug* using your computer power as shown [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html).

### RDP

As for GPU via RDP, it is mentioned [here](https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/knowledge-base/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-microsoft-remote-desktop/) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e139ec92-90d0-4639-a3b5-5a5a4a5b6a79/hardware-support-gpu-on-rdp-connection-to-windows-10-professional?forum=winRDc), e.g., that GPU rendering can be enabled via Group Policies.
I am not certain this includes anything about PyTorch computation.

Answer (score 3):

> **The key is that I'd like to continue using the machine while that person runs compute loads on it**

This is possible, but those compute loads are going to slow down the machine. I would be sure to set the priority of the processes running the compute loads to Below Normal if you want to prioritize your smooth operation. This means all default running processes will be prioritized for available CPU time before the compute loads, but another way to look at it is that if there are a LOT of other processes running on the same machine with Normal priority, that are also using up 100% of the CPU, the compute loads will get little to no CPU time. This is probably desired by you, and the odds that you're utilizing the CPU at 100% (or have a ton of processes running doing that for you somehow) are likely low.

> **As far as I know, that requirement excludes all forms of RDP/VNC, but I'm not sure about that (especially RDP): could you
> confirm/deny?**

That is correct. RDP from Starter/Student/Home/Pro versions of Windows have the intentional limitation of only one login at a time (exceptions in Enterprise). There are some **super** shady ways to break that so that it won't boot you out when the other person logs in remotely using RDP, but I believe discussing such things is not allowed on SuperUser and so that conversation dies here.

VNC/NX/Screensharing all will take over your currently logged in session and use it remotely, so definitely a no go.

> **I was thinking of running a SSH server. Would that work?**

Yes! This would definitely work, and Windows 10 has SSH built in by-default. You can activate it using the following steps:

1. Settings > Apps and click “Manage optional features” under Apps &
   features.
2. Click “Add a feature” at the top of the list of installed features.
   If you already have the SSH client installed, it will appear in the
   list here.
3. Scroll down, click the “OpenSSH Server” option, and click “Install”.

The person should be able to SSH in using a User Account, which you will want to set up for them, and issue command line commands to run processes while you are physically logged into the machine. Viola!

Answer (score 0):

Considering  the use-case is specific to getting [compute power for python/pytorch program](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2191) you should [setup an ssh server](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2020/05/21/ssh-server-on-windows-10.aspx#:%7E:text=You%20can%20install%20OpenSSH%20Server,OpenSSH%20Server%2C%20and%20clicking%20Install.&text=Once%20added%2C%20it%20will%20be,the%20list%20of%20optional%20features.&text=Once%20it%20is%20installed%2C%20you%20will%20need%20to%20start%20the%20service.) on the host with OpenSSH.

Even though it is possible to [setup ssh server on Windows 10](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2020/05/21/ssh-server-on-windows-10.aspx#:%7E:text=You%20can%20install%20OpenSSH%20Server,OpenSSH%20Server%2C%20and%20clicking%20Install.&text=Once%20added%2C%20it%20will%20be,the%20list%20of%20optional%20features.&text=Once%20it%20is%20installed%2C%20you%20will%20need%20to%20start%20the%20service.) it cannot be used as a full-featured Windows Server [due to limitations](https://serverfault.com/a/158638/357731), but it might be enough for executing python programs remotely. Setting up a windows server on your laptop would be another option depending on if you are doing this for long term and broader use.

---

[Getting Started with powershell on ssh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7)

[How to run a python script remotely via SSH on a Windows machine](https://serverfault.com/a/954858/357731)

Comment: "Even though it is possible to setup ssh server on Windows 10 it cannot be used as a complete server" This is blatantly wrong. SSH is a secure shell, in this case, into the windows command line instead of a Linux terminal. It's simply CMD instead of SH. That doesn't make it "incomplete". You can do anything from an SSH CMD shell that you could do from CMD the same as you can do whatever you need in an SSH BASH shell that you could do from BASH at the physical terminal. It's merely a way to connect to the machine securely and gain access to the command line.

Comment: My context here was never about how ssh is used or it's use it's if the usability differs in server vs non-server but rather how the OP's requirement could be easily handled by a server and it would be a better option. https://serverfault.com/a/158638/357731

Comment: Ah, the lack of delineation between OpenSSH Server and a physical server leaves much to the imagination. I highly recommend restructuring your answer for clarity. I'll suggest an edit, but, of course, do as you please.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all correct (at the time of this writing). However, I'd like to bring an alternative to the built-in Windows SSH server to your attention:

You may want to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), which has been around for about two decades, is well supported and constantly updated, and is very stable IMHO. It has OpenSSH included, and you can easily install the Cygwin OpenSSH server as a service. I am using such setups for many years and started with it long before Microsoft even thought about integrating a Linux subsystem or SSH into Windows.

In case you haven't heard about it yet: Cygwin mainly is a DLL which provides the most part of the Linux / Unix / Posix API under Windows so that very much of the Linux userland utilities can be ported to Windows. The nomenclature is a bit worrying, though, because Cygwin is also commonly used as the name of the Linux "distribution", that is, the Linux software which has been ported to Windows with the help of the Cygwin DLL and which is offered at the Cygwin website as well.

The advantage of Cygwin is that it provides a Linuxish environment, including C toolchains, the common scripting languages, bash etc. It depends on your friend's background if this is an advantage. In every case, a resulting advantage is that you can configure the OpenSSH server exactly as in Linux - there are plenty of tutorials covering that subject.

The disadvantage of Cygwin is that its OpenSSH server is (of course) not as deeply integrated into Windows as the built-in SSH server.

Regarding the method of access: OpenSSH server is regularly patched and very secure IMHO, so it would be safe (**in theory**) to configure your router with port forwarding so that your friend can connect directly to your PC via SSH. **However, the fact that this is considered bad style has its reasons.** Therefore, I recommend to configure a VPN between your friend and your router, using the strongest cryptography available at both ends, and run the SSH sessions over the VPN.

A final word regarding TeamViewer (since your bounty and some comments mention it):

This service is run by a German company which I personally trust; they have to adhere to strict data protection laws and would be instantly ruined if there was the slightest suspect or even a proof that they record or even decrypt sessions. However, due to the nature of their service, all traffic which is going over TeamViewer sessions is routed through their servers, so sniffing sessions would be theoretically possible possible for them (which, by the way, is true for all competing similar services / companies as well).

TeamViewer has assured multiple times that the sessions are end-to-end encrypted, which means that the traffic goes through their servers, but they technically are not even able to decrypt it, even if they want to do it. But once again, while I personally believe them, as long as their software is not open source, nobody can verify this statement, or whether they did implement encryption correctly.

Finally, as others already have pointed out, your friend won't be able to run his own TeamViewer session without disturbing you. TeamViewer is more a screen sharing solution: The other party can see what you do, and vice versa.

Therefore, I always prefer SSH or a VPN (based on open source software) over TeamViewer and similar services whenever possible.

Comment: What benefit would the OP receive from the added layer, and complexity, of Cygwin over the available OpenSSH available inside Windows 10 by default? I don't mean to step too hard on your toes, but this answer only answers 1/3rd of the question, does so by adding massive complexity, and uses a massive amount of subjective points. I really think you would have benefited from using a few comments instead of this guideline- abstract answer.

Comment: @DeeJayh Your comment is absolutely appropriate. This is why I explicitly stated that the other answers are right in the first sentence of my answer and tried to make clear that my answer only adds additional aspects to the other answers. However: As I have written, the benefit of Cygwin is the Linuxish environment it provides; it depends on the OP's friend's preferences whether this is an advantage. Secondly, Cygwin's OpenSSH is directly derived from Openssh.org, which is the best known and widespread SSH server. You can take any OpenSSH configuration, copy it to Cygwin, and you're done.

Comment: Plus, we should give *all* possible answers to a question, shouldn't we? After all, SuperUser is a place to learn, and I personally would regret if there was some policy saying that we only must post the "best" solution. Who would decide this? Coming back to SSH, I am so much used to Linux and OpenSSH that I never used the Windows built-in SSH server yet, because learning its configuration *for me* probably would be more complex than installing Cygwin (which I need anyway).

Comment: Don't misinterpret me. I'm not against alternative answers, in fact, viable alternatives are allowed per guidelines. My problem with your post is that you're suggesting a windows tagged question was better solved by adding the complexity of Linux to it, then showering the other 80%of the post with subjective opinions regarding cygwin, TeamViewer, etc.

Comment: In short, it's not a "viable alternative", it's an over complicated mess, it doesn't answer 2/3rds of the question, and it just doesn't feel like it properly addresses the question asked. Disclaimer:  I am a Linux guy too, my server has run Ubuntu for 7+ years. I'm very comfortable and familiar with it. This isn't a "bash something because it's different" type of thought.

Comment: What I wrote about TeamViewer are mostly facts. I just outlined (as a matter of fact) that all session traffic is routed through their servers and that they thus might be able to sniff it, and the legislation they are under. As I wrote, I am considering my answer an additional aspect. I don't see much sense in parroting what the other answers already have stated correctly, which is why I didn't answer all of the question (i.e. repeat the statements about Remote Desktop and friends). I guess that none of us will give up his point of view, especially regarding Cygwin, so let history decide :-)